# Disabling border-collapse for single columns and rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a little problem with my table. I want that the first column and the first row has separate borders, but the rest of the table has collapsed borders. I tested to use the border-collapse attribute on td's and th's but it seems like that it just works for the table tag. What do I have to do to realize this?

My table:

```
<table id=sptable>
...
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
table#sptable { border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide us some code to see the problem.

Comment: Interesting how would the very first cell look? Separated from both sides?

Comment: OK, I added it. So now I have td's and th's in the table and need to have some CSS on it on order to change it to border-collapse: separate (I guess).

Comment: @dfsq Yes. The first cell is separated from both sides

Comment: I dont see any td and th in your code... would you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? And it should be `id="sptable"` but maybe you have this in your real code right (cant see, because there is no code)

Comment: As you suspect, `border-collapse` is applied to the table and cannot applied to individual cells. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Comment: @DerVampyr Hier: http://jsfiddle.net/gh5hmda5/ As I mentioned, the first row should be separate from the rest of the table, and the first column too.

Comment: You can do it but its a bit hacky: http://jsfiddle.net/gh5hmda5/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for the first row you can add an empty row behind it like this:

```
<tr><td style="height: 20px;"></td></tr>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gh5hmda5/1/)

EDIT:

Well updated for cols too. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gh5hmda5/7/)
(same procedure, adding some th instead of tr)

Comment: Not bad. But there must be another solution for the cols :\

Comment: Why? Other way i see is to make it without a table, or just make a table for the timeelements and the header and timezones by divs